# Security issues with phonegap remote server access

Tags: jquery, security, cordova

OK so I was attempting to create a phoneGap app with remote server access and came accross this article by Sam Croft he used the jQuery.ajax() function to create a basic data request

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://yourdomain.com/your-data-request.php?foo=bar',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
        //data loaded
    },
    error: function(){
        //error loading data
    }
});
```

http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/

But wouldn't this approach create a security risk? Anybody who gets hold of your url "http://yourdomain.com/your-data-request.php" could access your data without a password wouldn't this be a problem? Or is there a way to allow only the app you create access?

Comment: I think the tutorial assumes the data is public.

Comment: Any other way of doing this without your data being public?

Answer (score 0):

well, it is also with a "Session conception" on the Server side.

you may use a user & password to login firstly, then set a session for that guy.

after that, any other pages/urls need to check that session.